# Type inference list with function composition

Tags: haskell, ghci, function-composition

I'm attempting to take the square of the sum of integers in Haskell using a fold. However, I'm getting a cryptic error from GHCi. Here is my one-liner:

```
((^2) . foldl) (+) 0 [1..100]
```

What I'm getting from GHCi is:

```
Prelude> ((^2) . foldl) (+) 0 [1..100]

<interactive>:19:3:
    No instance for (Num (b0 -> [b0] -> b0))
      arising from a use of `^'
    Possible fix:
      add an instance declaration for (Num (b0 -> [b0] -> b0))
    In the first argument of `(.)', namely `(^ 2)'
    In the expression: (^ 2) . foldl
    In the expression: ((^ 2) . foldl) (+) 0 [1 .. 100]
```

I think the problem is in the list I'm passing in at the end based on this type declaration.

```
Prelude> :t ((^2) . foldl) (+) 0 [1..100]
((^2) . foldl) (+) 0 [1..100]
  :: (Enum b, Num b, Num (b -> [b] -> b)) => b
```

Can anyone give me some insight into why this type is expecting an `Enum` and any way to explicitly cast the list so that I can debug this function? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 9):

Yeah, this remains one of the most ridiculous and useless error messages GHC produces.

First, ignoring the message, consider the type of `foldl` and `(.)`:

```
foldl :: (a -> b -> a) -> a -> [b] -> a
(.) :: (b -> c) -> (a -> b) -> a -> c
```

Note that `(.)` composes using only the first arguments. Because of currying, a function with "multiple" arguments is really a function of one argument that returns another function. So in the expression `((^2) . foldl)` the "return type" of `foldl` is `a -> [b] -> a`, which is what it tries to compose with `(^ 2)`.

And because the error message is dumb, it complains that there's no `Num` instance for `a -> [b] -> a` in order to compose it with `(^2) :: Num a => a -> a` and suggests you add one.

What you wanted is something like this: `((^2) . foldl (+) 0)`. That said, using the (lazy) `foldl` is probably a bad idea here. Better to use the strict `foldl'` or, better still, the built-in `sum` function: `(^2) . sum`

Also, the `Enum` constraint mentioned in the type is irrelevant, and in fact correct--the `Enum` type class provides the functions used to interpret the range notation. So `(Enum b, Num b) => ...` means that `b` is a numeric type that can be enumerated, which is exactly what you need for the expression `[1 .. 100]`.

Answer (score 5):

The correct way to write this is `(^2) . foldl (+) 0 :: Num a => [a] -> a` or `(^2) . foldl (+) 0 $ [1..100] :: (Num a, Enum a) => a`. When you do `(^2) . foldl` by itself you try to square an argument of the *first* return type of `foldl`, which is a function `a -> [a] -> a`. The error declares this: it doesn't have a `Num` instance for this kind of function so it can't dispatch an appropriate power function `(^)`.

Generally, think of composition `(.)` as something that only works on functions of single inputs. The type is indicative of this

```
(.) :: (b -> c) -> (a -> b) -> a -> c
```

and while there are more general uses of it, they're a little difficult to find.

So my solution works because I apply arguments directly to `foldl` before composing it. These arguments make `foldl (+) 0 :: Num a => [a] -> a` a function of a single input argument.

Answer (score 0):

Good answers have been given, but perhaps it's more straightforward to write it

`(^2) $ foldl (+) 0 [1..100]`

The expression `foldl (+) 0 [1..100]` works by itself, which helps if you're trying to understand how foldl works, and then the result is passed to the `(^2)` . Written as a function

`f list = (^2) $ foldl (+) 0 list`

Comment: Even more straightforward: `foldl (+) 0 [1..100] ^ 2`.